# get server url in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

Is there any way I can get the url of the application inside a rake task?
I'm running heroku, so maybe there is a way I can get hold of the appname?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the following in my Rakefile:

```
task(:foo => :environment) do
  puts ENV['APP_NAME']
end
```

and it successfully returned Heroku's application name, my_foo_app. when I ran the command:

```
heroku rake foo --app my_foo_app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a config variable with the app URL using

```
heroku config:add APP_URL=http://myapp.com
```

Then you can get the value inside your rake task (or anywhere in your app) using `ENV['APP_URL']`

Documentation: http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars